# Numerical instability in cosh and sinh - integral functions

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I'm trying to calculate the function:

```
CoshIntegral[x] Sinh[x] - Cosh[x] SinhIntegral[x]
```

Unfortunately *Mathematica* seems to hit a point (x~20) and things become unstable (see plot below), there shouldn't be any infinities in the area, so I am rather confused as to what is going on!

[image: plot of above function]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are calculating the small difference between numbers which are getting quite large and the default `WorkingPrecision` of `Plot` (which is `MachinePrecision`, usually about 16) is just not high enough.

So simply increase the `WorkingPrecision` of `Plot`, e.g.

```
Plot[CoshIntegral[x] Sinh[x] - Cosh[x] SinhIntegral[x], {x, 0, 40}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 40, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

I verified this behavior. I tried to increase `$MaxExtraPrecision` but I didn't get any improvement.

A solution is to increase `WorkingPrecision` in `Plot`:

```
Plot[CoshIntegral[x] Sinh[x] - Cosh[x] SinhIntegral[x], {x, 0, 30}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

At last I created Cosh and Sinh integrals below with increased WorkingPrecision inside NIntegrate.

```
chi[z_] := N[EulerGamma + Log[z] + 
             NIntegrate[(Cosh[t] - 1)/t, {t, 0, z}, WorkingPrecision -> 50], 50]

shi[z_] := NIntegrate[Sinh[t]/t, {t, 0, z}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

Then we can define `res[x]` as:

```
res[x_] := N[chi[x] Sinh[x] - shi[x] Cosh[x],50]
```

And `Plot` it:

```
Plot[res[x], {x, 0, 30}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-1, 1}}]]
```

It is a little bit slow but it works.

To check special values you can also use [CoshIntegral Evaluation](http://functions.wolfram.com/webMathematica/FunctionEvaluation.jsp?name=CoshIntegral) to verify the correctness for `chi` function above.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately when I tried using the above method I still had the wacky behaviour. I think the Logarithm should be a natural log rather than base 10, and the integral should go to 0 as x->infty

Comment: @jake I searched on http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/CoshIntegral/ and it seems that `log` has base 10. Also there you can download a PDF file (after completing a small form) with all information about the function. What version of Mathematica are you using ?

Comment: I'm using mathematica 9. Thanks for that I will have a flick through.
I was under the impression though, that the function Log[] in mathematica was by default a natural logarithm?

Comment: @Jake yes you are right. I got confused - it is the natural logarithm. And for this change I get very strange results... I will update shortly.

Comment: @tchronis You updated your answer at the same time I posted mine!

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar yes you were seconds faster than me! :-)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to setting the input precision is to ask for enough output accuracy.  The main idea is to set the precision of the input to `Infinity` and use `N` to get the desired accuracy -- something like this:

```
N[f[SetPrecision[x, Infinity], 6]
```

Here's such an wrapper for a function:

```
Options[nEval] := {AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, "MaxExtraPrecision" -> Automatic};
nEval[f_, x_?NumericQ, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 
     OptionValue["MaxExtraPrecision"] /. Automatic -> $MaxExtraPrecision},
   N[f[SetPrecision[x, Infinity]], OptionValue[AccuracyGoal] /. Automatic -> 6]
   ];
```

Then

```
myF[x_] := CoshIntegral[x] Sinh[x] - Cosh[x] SinhIntegral[x];

Plot[nEval[myF, x], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The precision is adapted to what is needed.

```
Plot[nEval[myF, x], {x, 30, 60}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-0.35, 0}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But one can still get a catastrophic loss of precision, due to the limit `$MaxExtraPrecision`.

```
Plot[nEval[myF, x], {x, 30, 100}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-0.35, 0}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In that case, one can raise the amount of extra precision allowed, even to `Infinity`.  (In some cases, it might take an exorbitant amount of time to finish, but in this case, it is still quick.)

```
Plot[nEval[myF, x, "MaxExtraPrecision" -> Infinity], {x, 30, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-0.35, 0}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

A bit of an aside, but the limit behavior of this expression has a readily found simple form:

```
Simplify[Re@ 
 (*the series expansion has an imaginary part that asymptotically vanishes*)
         Normal@Series[
              CoshIntegral[x] Sinh[x] - SinhIntegral[x] Cosh[x],
                 {x, Infinity, 3}], Assumptions -> {x > 0}]
```

(*  -(2+x^2)/x^3  *)

Now you can plot w/o using excessive precision:

```
Plot[Piecewise[ {
   {CoshIntegral[x] Sinh[x] - SinhIntegral[x] Cosh[x], x < 10},
   {-((2 + x^2)/x^3), True}
      }], {x, 0, 30},  PlotRange -> All ]
```