# Dealing with square roots

Tags: numerical-value

Consider following expression:
$$
\sqrt{-\left(2 \sqrt{x^{-8/3}-x^{-4/3}+1}\, x^{4/3}+5\right) x^{4/3}+4 \sqrt{x^{-8/3}-x^{-4/3}+1}\, x^{4/3}+2 x^{8/3}+5}
$$
In code:

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[
   -(2 Sqrt[x^(-8/3) - x^(-4/3) + 1] x^(4/3) + 5) x^(4/3)
   + 4 Sqrt[x^(-8/3) - x^(-4/3) + 1] x^(4/3) + 2 x^(8/3) + 5
]
```

Why in Mathematica one can see non smoothness at $x\sim10^4$?

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10^4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I guess, it is a numerical issue, but then how one can deal with it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE.  Please include your expression as *Mathematica* code for easy handling by those who wish to answer.

Comment: Increase the `WorkingPrecision`: `Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10^4}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]` gives [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cjlN8.png).

Comment: It does seem disappointing that the precision is not defined automatically based on the plot range and proportional value of a pixel.

Comment: Similar: [3152](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3152), [7109](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7109), [18126](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18126), [38769](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38769).  N.B. The solution `WorkingPrecision -> Infinity` from an answer to [7019] does not work on this example; but `PPlot[N[f[x], 8], {x, 0, 10^4}, Exclusions -> None, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity]` does.  I'll propose [3152] as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using WorkingPrecision as pointed out in the comments, it is often more efficient and reduces numerical noise to `Simplify` (or in some cases `FullSimplify`) the function's definition.

Original definition

```
f1[x_] := Sqrt[-(2 Sqrt[x^(-8/3) - x^(-4/3) + 1] x^(4/3) + 5) x^(4/3) + 
   4 Sqrt[x^(-8/3) - x^(-4/3) + 1] x^(4/3) + 2 x^(8/3) + 5]
```

`Simplify` once by using `Set` rather than `SetDelayed`.

```
f2[x_] = Sqrt[-(2 Sqrt[x^(-8/3) - x^(-4/3) + 1] x^(4/3) + 5) x^(4/3) + 
     4 Sqrt[x^(-8/3) - x^(-4/3) + 1] x^(4/3) + 2 x^(8/3) + 5] // Simplify;
```

Or use `Evaluate` with `SetDelayed`.

```
f3[x_] := Evaluate[
  Sqrt[-(2 Sqrt[x^(-8/3) - x^(-4/3) + 1] x^(4/3) + 5) x^(4/3) + 
     4 Sqrt[x^(-8/3) - x^(-4/3) + 1] x^(4/3) + 2 x^(8/3) + 5] // Simplify]

Timing[Plot[#[x], {x, 0, 10^4}, WorkingPrecision -> 15];][[1]] & /@ {f1, f2, 
  f3}
```

> {1.472757, 0.066547, 0.066083}